# Combinations problem with factorial too high to be calculated

Tags: probability

so I know that combination problems are usually quite simple but in this case I am not really sure how to proceed, I hope the question would not be regarded as too easy.

Situation: I have a data file composed of a 2X2 matrix which comes from a camera (pretty much a picture). Now, for each picture there will be a given number of pixels which are going to be above a certain threshold defined by me. My statistical problem is the following: if I take two pictures, what is the probability that AT LEAST one of the pixels above the threshold share the same position in the two pictures?

This is how I tried to solve the problem: first of all I did my analysis on the picture to quantify the number of pixels above the threshold, and here are the numbers of the pixel above the threshold and of the total number of pixels in the picture:

Pixels_above_threshold: 360

total_number_pixels: 1048576

Next, I tried to calculate what is the probability that in the following, hypothetical picture (assuming the total number of the pixels above the threshold remains the same), ZERO of the pixels above the threshold share the same position as the first picture. My idea was then after finding that probability to simply subtract that to 1 thereby obtaining the number that I need.

This is the formula that I wanted to use:

$$
P = \frac{\frac{(1048576-360)!}{((1048576-360)-360)!*360!}}{\frac{1048576!}{(1048576-360)!*360!}}
$$

However there must be something very obviously wrong, as when I try to perform the factorials the numbers are simply too high to be calculated. I have a feeling that I am missing something very basic, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Hope somebody can help and that the question is not too embarrassing.

Thanks.

Comment: Use logarithms.  Even spreadsheets include log factorial functions.

Comment: Indeed, use logarithms of both sides of the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of numbers cancel in the factorials. I recommend writing $k=360$ and $N=1048576$ to make the algebra easier to follow. Then your formula for the probability of no pixel being chosen twice is

$${N-k \choose k}/{N \choose k}$$

which simplifies to

$$\frac{(N-k)!}{(N-2k)!k!} / \frac{N!}{(N-k)!k!} = \frac{(N-k)!(N-k)!}{(N-2k)!N!}$$

writing out the factorials, a lot of terms cancel and you get

$$\frac{(N-k)(N-k-1)\cdots(N-2k+1)}{N(N-1)\cdots(N-k+1)}$$

which after taking the terms in pairs, gives

$$(1-\frac{k}{N})(1-\frac{k}{N-1}) \cdots (1-\frac{k}{N-k+1}) = \prod_{u=0}^{k-1}(1-\frac{k}{N-u})$$

which can be plugged into a calculator or computer. I think this gives about $0.884$ so the probability of a coincidence is $0.12$ to 2 decimal places.